# Extract a JSON string from a Text File using pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a TEXT file with 4 fields and 3rd field is JSON string which I want to extract and create a separate column in dataframe.

```
pk,line,json,date
DBG,CDL,{"line":"CDL","stn":"DBG","latitude":"12.298915","longitude":"143.846263","isInterchange":true,"isIncidentStn":false,"stnKpis":[{"code":"PCD_PCT","value":0.1,"valueCreatedTs":1667361600000,"confidence":"50.0",}]},20221102
```

Expected output format in dataframe:

[image]

I tried below command , but it didn't produce expected output

```
df=spark.read.csv("/content/sample_data/file.txt",header=True,inferSchema=True,quote='"',escape='"')
```

spark version:2.4
python version:3.6

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv file using pyspark into a dataframe.

df = spark.read.csv("/tmp/resources/zipcodes.csv")

Then

json_string = json.loads(df.iloc["json"])

Comment: df = spark.read.csv("/tmp/resources/zipcodes.csv") --> this doesnt read entire JSON string, it reads till 2nd field of the json string

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df =spark.createDataFrame([('DBG','CDL',{"line":"CDL","stn":"DBG","latitude":"12.298915","longitude":"143.846263","isInterchange":'true',"isIncidentStn":'false',"stnKpis":[{"code":"PCD_PCT","value":0.1,"valueCreatedTs":1667361600000,"confidence":"50.0",}]},'20221102')],
                         ('pk','line','json','date'))

##Every df has an underlying rdd, select column into df and send it to rdd
rdd=df.select(col("json").alias("jsoncol")).rdd.map(lambda x: x.jsoncol)

#Read rdd
schema spark.read.json(rdd).show()
```

Comment: Hi @wwnde, Thanks for your answer. My bad that I didnt put expected output in the question. Now I have updated with expected output format. Could you change your answer accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: Whats the major difference between your input and output?

Comment: I will have to put this output in hive as a table

Comment: I tried  this command df=spark.read.csv("/content/sample_data/file.txt",header=True,inferSchema=True,quote='"',escape='"') , but didn't produce expected output